# Conflicting information for Crete bus routes

Tags: buses, crete

I am currently planning travel to visit Samariá Gorge from Chania. I intend to start from the north at Xyloskalo and descend through the gorge and ultimately reach Agia Roumeli in the south. I've [read](https://www.samaria.gr/en/tips-crossing-samaria/) that in Agia Roumeli you can then get a boat to Sougia, at which you can then get a bus back to Chania.

However, when I search for routes from Chania to Xyloskalo or Sougia to Chania on KTEL's (Crete's bus service) official [website](https://www.e-ktel.com/en/) I keep getting "No route found for the selected locations at the selected date.", regardless of which date I select. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: I can suggest using the apps Moovit or Rome2Rio for finding directions not available on Apple/Google Maps.

Comment: @noreputationplz thanks for the recommendations. I'm moreso concerned about the official bus service claiming there is no timetable for those routes, regardless of what third-party sources say.

Comment: Are you looking for more than a few days ahead? If so, the new schedule may not be published yet. But on the other hand, the bus may only run in the summer schedule which is not yet published.

Comment: @Willeke I am looking in June, but searching for the same timetable even tomorrow yields the same result. It's a possibility that it's a summer-only schedule which is not yet published. Hopefully someone familiar with Crete's bus services can advise.

Answer (score 3):

[This Tripadvisor post](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g189415-i714-k11251829-Chania_Omalos_Samaria_Gorge_KTEL_buses_2018_no_more-Chania_Town_Chania_Prefecture_Crete.html) suggests that the buses don't run in the winter as the gorge is closed - it looks like the timetables will be posted nearer to when the buses start running again.

It also suggests that there is only one bus a day to Omalos for much of the season, at 7:45. It might work out better to get an organised tour - we did one when we visited Crete a couple of years ago, and it included a coach from our hotel to Omalos, the ferry and the coach back from Chora Sfakion.

Comment: An organised tour is a good recommendation actually. I've just looked into a few and overall the reviews are great. Do you recall who you booked with?

Comment: Not offhand, sorry! we booked it through a little tourist agency near our hotel in Rethymno.

Answer (score -3):

HELLO MY FRIEND I AM FROM CRETE TRAVELING SOUTH WITH ''KTEL'' IT IS NOT THE MOST COVINIENT WAY .AS A MATTER OF FACT THE KTEL ROUTE AT THIS LOCATIONS DEPARTS ONCE OR TWICE A DAY .YOU DEFINATELY DONT NEED TO BOOK A TICKET IN ADVANCE.WHEN YOU VISITED IT DID NOT MALFUCTIONED ,THEY JUST NOT SUPPORT BOOKING YET .IF YOU WANT TO TRAVEL TO SOUTH CRETE , YOU NEED TO CONTUCT THEM BY PHONE FOR TIMETABLES AND PRICES (IF THEY DON'T SPEAK ENGLISH TRY LATER).MY SUGGESTION FOR YOU IS IF YOU HAVE A DRIVER LICENSE BE OVER 18 AND YOU HAVE IT AT LEAST FOR 1 YEAR RENT CAR.IF YOU ARE NOT FROM EUROPE YOU NEED TO APLY  FOR AN INTERNATIONAL DRIVERS LICENSE IN YOUR COUNTRY (COST 90EURO 100$)

Comment: Please don't post entirely in capitals, it is considered 'shouting'. Also, hiring a car is not practical for visiting Samaria as they would have to get back to the car from the bottom of the gorge.

Comment: forget the car stick with the ktel ,arrive in time to the ktel  station (30 - 40mins before departure ) dont wear flip flops dress properly . ( the thing with the car ,climb up climb down the gorge is kind of military excercise i didnt consider you as tourist but as rock climber)